# How can i add a payment method in wix

Tags: velo

I want to use a 3rd party payment method that does not have a direct connection to wix in my country. Can I do this with coding? How can I do ? I tried to add directly at wix payment methods but like I said wix dont support directly

Comment: You might want to try posting this question to https://www.reddit.com/r/WixHelp/ and provide more details there such as the country you're in and the 3rd party you intend to use.